# spring integration int-redis:outbound-gateway exception

Tags: spring-integration

used a RedisMessageTranfomer to push a message to have a payload of test with a header redis_command=GET to redis outbound gateway and go the exception listed below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/redis http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/redis/spring-integration-redis.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xmlns:int-redis="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/redis"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:si-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml">


    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="omega"
        request-channel="channel3" path="/omega" supported-methods="GET,POST"
        reply-channel="channel5" />


    <int:channel id="channel3">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel3LoggingChannel" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="channel3LoggingChannel"
        level="INFO" expression="'*** Channel3 Log ' + headers + ' -&gt; ' + payload">
    </int:logging-channel-adapter>

    <int:transformer 
        output-channel="channel4" input-channel="channel3"
        ref="redisMessageTransformer"
        method="transform">
    </int:transformer>

    <bean id="redisMessageTransformer"
    class="org.springframework.integration.samples.http.RedisMessageTransformer"/>


    <int:channel id="channel4">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel4LoggingChannel" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="channel4LoggingChannel"
        level="INFO" expression="'*** Channel4 Log ' + headers + ' -&gt; ' + payload">
    </int:logging-channel-adapter>


    <int-redis:outbound-gateway request-channel="channel4"
        reply-channel="channel5" redis-template="redisTemplate"
        command-expression="'GET'" />


    <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redisConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:use-pool="true" p:host-name="127.0.0.1" p:port="6379" />

    <bean 
    id="stringRedisSerializer" 
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>

    <bean id="payloadArgumentsStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.integration.samples.http.PayloadArgumentsStrategy"/>


    <int:channel id="channel5">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="channel5LoggingChannel" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="channel5LoggingChannel"
        level="INFO" expression="'*** Channel5 Log ' + headers + ' -&gt; ' + payload">
    </int:logging-channel-adapter>


</beans>

package org.springframework.integration.samples.http;

import org.springframework.integration.redis.support.RedisHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;


public class RedisMessageTransformer {

    public Object transform(Object object)
    {
        Object m = object;

        System.out.println("*** object.getClass().getName = " + object.getClass().getName());

        m = MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").setHeader(RedisHeaders.COMMAND, "GET").build();

        System.out.println("*** m = " + m);

        return m;
    }

}
```

Exception

```
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.execute(Ljava/lang/String;[[B)Ljava/lang/Object;

    at org.springframework.integration.redis.outbound.RedisOutboundGateway$1.doInRedis(RedisOutboundGateway.java:125)

    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:162)

    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:133)

    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:121)

    at org.springframework.integration.redis.outbound.RedisOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(RedisOutboundGateway.java:121)

    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
```

What needs to be changed to get redis-outboundgateway to read (GET) a value from redis>?

Answer (score 0):

> org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.execute(Ljava/lang/String;[[B)Ljava/lang/Object;

H-m... Which version of Spring Data Redis do you use?

Try to use that on which comes as transitive dependency for `spring-integration-redis-4.0`